# Close range stereoscopic recording

Tags: dslr, focal-length, 3d, chroma-key, stereoscopy

So I have some work for a client; I have never tried to shoot 3D before but I have an idea how it can be done. So the situation is: I have a wide green screen and I want to record stereoscopic videos from different angles. I thought it would be easy to do with two DSLRs but the problem is that I don't have a beamsplitter rig, and as far as I know a side-by-side rig won't work since the actor is too close (within 15 feet). I also know that the interactial seperation between lenses must be about 65mm (for male adult) but using two DSLRs near each other, the distance will be greater than that. So how do I rig two DSLRs for close-range stereoscopic recording?

I thought for a while it would be better to buy a 3D camcorder but I won't have full control (plus a pro 3D camcorder is expensive). Are there any affordable solutions to do the job? (Nothing DIY please. I can buy stuff but under $1000).

Maybe I am mistaken and it is possible to shoot 3D using a side-by-side rig for close range so let me know.

Any question about details I am ready to answer if I wasn't clear enough.

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Presumably, answers to this would also apply to close-range stereoscopic _photography_, not just video, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are old approaches to triggering two cameras simultaneously.  While the [Nikon AR-4](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/nikonf2/accessories/htmls/ff2cables.htm) has two different threads (it was designed for a macro system where you want the lens disconnected from the body to be triggered at the same time as the shutter) - similar dual threaded cable releases can be found if one looks.  Note, however, that this requires a threaded shutter release too - something not often found on modern cameras.

Another approach is to use a system that electronically fires multiple cameras with a modern cable release.  [Breeze Systems](http://www.breezesys.com/purchase_dslrrempro_mc.htm) has one such system (which does fall into your price range - assuming you are working with various EOS bodies and a windows system).

Both of those approaches still require a side by side rig, which as you pointed out isn't necessarily going to work because the body of each gets in the way of the other.

But, there are other approaches to getting a 3d image - split capture two images on the same exposure.  You'll be sacrificing image size (the 20 megapixel image will now be 2x 10 megapixels images), but it also solves the problem of triggering the camera.

One such device can be seen:

[image]

[Loreo](http://www.loreo.com) makes [one such](http://www.loreo.com/pages/products/loreo_3dlenscap9005.html) for APS-C sized sensors.  The full frame product (9004) was discontinued earlier this month (October 2014), but can still be found on various shopping sites or used systems.  These will likely be in the $150 - $200 range.  I would not expect great things for the quality.  I would also make sure you consider the associated time spent in fixing each frame from 2x 2d to 3d.

Note that if you are after 3-d *video* it may be easier to get a 3d lens for the appropriate camera.  For example, [this one for a panasonic camcorder](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/849146-REG/Panasonic_VW_CLT2_VW_CLT2_3D_CONVERSION_LENS.html).

Comment: Thanks.. but I checked this kind of 3D lenses.. the problem that they are really slow; f/11 and f/22.. My concern now is about the distance between the two dslr lenses which must be about 65mm.. but the dslr bodies are larger than that so I can't get them close enough.. So what cant I do about this detail?

Comment: Where can I get a gear like this? What is called actually? (that thing mounted on the tripod which link the two dslrs ledametrix.com/lspro/v3mountc.htm

Comment: It is often known as a dual or twin camera bracket. For example, from Amazon [Dual Camera Photo Bracket Mount 2 Twin Cameras for 3D 3-D Stereo Stereoscopic Photography](http://www.amazon.com/Camera-Bracket-Cameras-Stereoscopic-Photography/dp/B004HK0RXY). Other approaches include a [tripod utility bar](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/707200-REG/Vanguard_MULTI_MOUNT_6_Multi_Mount_6_Tripod_Utility.html) on which you put two tripod heads (or [4 heads](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/552742-REG/Manfrotto_131DDB_131DDB_Tripod_Accessory_Arm.html/prm/alsVwDtl)).

Comment: I think the first stuff will do the job.. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

As there is no way to synchronize the frame capture times between the two DSLRs, you cannot record in 3D. You would need to make some kind of a synchronization circuit and for that you need to hack into the DSLRs - way too complex for your project I guess.

You can create 3D images though this way as single-triggering two cameras using one wire or wireless remote is possible.

By the way: rent, rather than buy, a 3D camera, if you do not need it on the long run...

Comment: I think the main problem is not about synchronisation because I can adjust this later using a software right? My concern now is about the distance between the two dslr lenses which must be about 65mm.. but the dslr bodies are larger than that so I can't get them close enough.. So what cant I do about this detail?

Comment: Where can I get a gear like this? What is called actually? (that thing mounted on the tripod which link the two dslrs   http://www.ledametrix.com/lspro/v3mountc.htm

Comment: No, you cannot synchronize the two streams in software. I would look very flickery. Also, the two timebase of the two camera will be sightly different.

Comment: I have no clue about your other questions.

Comment: Can't sync even if I am using the same dslr and same memory card size and class?

Comment: I am unaware of such a solution. It is theoretically possible, but given the framerate (25 fps), the resulting video will be inferior in quality. You may try to use two identical DSLRs that have high framerate (50 fps or preferably way above). What you need is a frame interpolator software of some sort. Even with audio, that is rather tricky (need an upconvert+resample+downconvert solution of high quality).

Comment: Yea I think that's what I am going to do.. No worries about the audio I am not going to record it.. One more question if you don't mind (just to conclude); if you were going to do such work (stereo on green screen) would you work with a simple stereoscopic camera (like panasonic lumix) or prefer two dslrs? Thanks for help..

Comment: I don't think using two DSLRs is feasible at all. I would rent a stereoscopic camera.